# Google is wiping my EXIF data, gives it back in a JSON file. Any already built tool that restore the tags?

Tags: exiftool, google-photos

So I've been uploading photos to google for ages and noticed something by accident the other day.  My photos are losing their EXIF data courtesy of Google!

I read I can use their data exporter (takeout) to get them back but evidently that too has changed and now you get a JSON file and your image (without any EXIF data) in it.  Are there any tools that will re-unite this data or do I have to write my own?

Alternatively, is there a way, other than the google **takeout** tool that does actually export your EXIF tags or do they strip them on the way in and they are gone forever????  I'm using a NIKON to take the good shots and they have tons of tags.

---

**Update**.  I've just checked again while trying to take some screenshots of the tags for this question and the tags are there.  Not sure what was going on the other day, but today the tags are present and the file downloaded is the exact same file that was uploaded.  No idea what was happening before.

I'm going to accept the photos-sync answer below so this does not appear to be an unanswered question but maybe the real answer is reboot your mac and check again.....

---

This is the JSON file they send to go with my photo.  There are no Nikon tags in there and the image file is completely stripped of all metadata so it is not a question of data in multiple places.

```
{
  "title": "DSC_0052.JPG",
  "description": "",
  "imageViews": "1",
  "creationTime": {
    "timestamp": "1660755243",
    "formatted": "Aug 17, 2022, 4:54:03 PM UTC"
  },
  "photoTakenTime": {
    "timestamp": "1660730302",
    "formatted": "Aug 17, 2022, 9:58:22 AM UTC"
  },
  "geoData": {
    "latitude": 40.4116867,
    "longitude": -3.6894917,
    "altitude": 628.0,
    "latitudeSpan": 0.0,
    "longitudeSpan": 0.0
  },
  "geoDataExif": {
    "latitude": 40.4116867,
    "longitude": -3.6894917,
    "altitude": 628.0,
    "latitudeSpan": 0.0,
    "longitudeSpan": 0.0
  },
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/WwRXFQzbe_n6GLClmD57yZjurFtEr1RPn3hhq1QMxfi2o301fLoW--a2G084gnVyAAzGbhVE3rjaNcLoPLnBX70wGcrvhTPKoiUeuY5R",
  "googlePhotosOrigin": {
    "webUpload": {
      "computerUpload": {
      }
    }
  },
  "photoLastModifiedTime": {
    "timestamp": "1660755334",
    "formatted": "Aug 17, 2022, 4:55:34 PM UTC"
  }
}
```

Comment: That JSON doesn't looks like a measly extract of the EXIF data. Are you sure the files you uploaded had EXIF tags and that Google Takeout does not exclude those tags anymore? [This forum post from december 2020 states that EXIF tags are included](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/89351441?hl=en&msgid=89420657). What happens if you upload a photo with known EXIF tags and then download the same file through Google Takeout?

Comment: I upload an image, put it in an "album" and download it.  One has all of the Nikon tags in it including everything about the camera, GPS, etc....  The one pulled back with takeout has none and just this JSON info

Comment: I've just done the following: I found a file from my Canon 550D with EXIF, IPTC and GPS tags. Uploaded it to photos.google.com by dragging/dropping it into the browser, it said it was uploaded as "Storage saver". Added the photo to a new album. Downloaded the photo by going the three dot menu and pressing "Download". Downloaded the photo by exporting the album via Google Takeout. Then I compared the original with the Downloaded and Takeout image using Beyond Compare. All EXIF, IPTC and GPS tags were identical, except for some minor differences (e.g. maker notes timezone offset, image size).

Comment: So... something is up. Perhaps you've uploaded the images through a different method? Or the software you're viewing EXIF tags with doesn't read it correctly?

Comment: Glad that you got it working. Feel free to post your update as an answer and accept that, as that is in the end what solved yiur issue.

Comment: "uploading photos to google" What does that mean? Which Google service, and how are you uploading them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Alternatively, is there a way, other than the google takeout tool that does actually export your EXIF tags

The [gphotos-sync](https://github.com/gilesknap/gphotos-sync) tool seems to export the photos with EXIF tags intact, but is limited [by some bugs in the Google API](https://github.com/gilesknap/gphotos-sync/issues/119). Because of that it doesn't export the location tags for example.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my preview tool on my macbook was just not displaying the tags.  After a reboot everything was fine.  What a relief